# PUSH Notifications to an iOS app in TestFlight are failing with INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, testflight

## Context

I'm developing an iOS application for a client, so I'll be using a fake name for that here. Let's suppose it's called "App".

For making my life easier (someone might question my sanity), I have two targets for my app:

1. A version that I send to my client for homologation:

   - Identifier: App (Development)
   - Bundle ID: br.com.team.app-dev
   - Xcode Target: App Development
2. The App Store version:

   - Identifier: App
   - Bundle ID: br.com.team.app
   - Xcode Target: App

For the rest of this discussion, mind only the Development version: I publish it through TestFlight, so the client can homologate it.

The application must receive remote PUSH Notifications. You can check the related configurations in this album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPYO.jpg.

Basically, I have a Apple Push Services certificate for the `br.com.team.app-dev` and iOS Distribution certificate that is involved in the publication of the app to TestFlight.

The Apple ID `br.com.team.app-dev` is configured for Push Notifications (as you can see in the Distribution column of the third screenshot).

In the forth screenshot, I'm only showing that there's a provisioning profile link all this things together.

In Xcode, I enabled the Push Notifications capability for the App Development target. I was hoping to show that the archive that I generated also had the apns-production entitlement, but, for some reason I can't imagine, my Xcode decided to not render the list of entitlements when I expand them), but trust me on that - it was there.

The application requests a PUSH token to Apple in its AppDelegate, as usual, and posts it to a server, and this server has an administrative interface where it's possible to publish message for the users.

The server is implemented in Java (a client's restriction) using [Spring](https://spring.io/), and I'm using [Java-APNS](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns), but I've tried other options (at least I'm sure I tried [JavaPNS](https://github.com/fernandospr/javapns-jdk16)).

From my Keychain, I exported both my Apple Push Services certificate and my private key (by selecting both of them and clicking in File > Export Items, as described in the APNS documentation). The resulting file was uploaded to the server, and it's being used when I'm actually posting the notifications.

Both the application and the server's code were developed by me.

## Problem

When I try to post a PUSH Notification, I'm being notified that the device's PUSH token is invalid.

## Code

Here's the code from the server:

```
ApnsService apnsService = APNS.newService()
    .withCert(certificate, password)
    .withAppleDestination(production)
    .withDelegate(new ApnsDelegate() {

        @Override
        public void messageSent(ApnsNotification message, boolean resent) {
            System.out.println("Message sent: " + message + " (resent: " + resent + ")");
        }

        @Override
        public void messageSendFailed(ApnsNotification message, Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Message send failed: " + message);
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed(DeliveryError e, int messageIdentifier) {
            System.err.println("Connection closed: " + messageIdentifier);
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void cacheLengthExceeded(int newCacheLength) {
            System.err.println("Cache length exceeded: " + newCacheLength);
        }

        @Override
        public void notificationsResent(int resendCount) {
            System.out.println("Notifications resent: " + resendCount);
        }

    })
    .build();

List<String> results = pushTokenDAO.getPushTokens();
System.out.println("PUSH Tokens: " + results);

String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(text).build();
System.out.println("PUSH Payload: " + payload);

apnsService.push(results, payload);

Map<String, Date> inactiveDevices = apnsService.getInactiveDevices();
Set<String> inactiveDeviceTokens = inactiveDevices.keySet();
System.out.println("Inactive tokens (they'll be removed): " + inactiveDeviceTokens);

for (String inactiveDeviceToken : inactiveDeviceTokens) {
    pushTokenDAO.deletePushToken(inactiveDeviceToken);
}
```

## Test

From the server's administrative interface, I tried sending a message with "Test" as content. Here are the logs that were printed:

```
PUSH Tokens: [ce0676a133c304eaa7b322338c7af4b7323cb9cffa9c6998dbce32dd22081173]
PUSH Payload: {"aps":{"alert":"Test"}}
Message sent: Message(Id=6; Token=CE0676A133C304EAA7B322338C7AF4B7323CB9CFFA9C6998DBCE32DD22081173; Payload={"aps":{"alert":"Test"}}) (resent: false)
Connection closed: 6
INVALID_TOKEN
Message send failed: Message(Id=6; Token=CE0676A133C304EAA7B322338C7AF4B7323CB9CFFA9C6998DBCE32DD22081173; Payload={"aps":{"alert":"Test"}})
com.notnoop.exceptions.ApnsDeliveryErrorException: Failed to deliver notification with error code 8
Notifications resent: 0
Inactive tokens (they'll be removed): []
```

## Question

Any ideas on why this is happening? I've tried so many things that I can't remember, but I'm willing to retry all of them by your suggestions!

Sorry for the long post, and for the bad English. Thanks in advance!